# gsutil command error - [No space left on device. This can happen if gsutil is configured to save tracker files to an unwritable directory]

Tags: gsutil, cp, tracker

When trying to run the gsutil command, as follows:

```
mkdir -p train_data
gsutil -m cp -r $train_data_gcs_path train_data/
```

The above commands copies upto 80% data out of 105GB of data and then throws this error:

```
CommandException: Couldn't write tracker file (/root/.gsutil/tracker-files/download_TRACKER_76f3482c2cf496af33c4d70aeb7ac16c55689723.rquet__JSON.etag): No space left on device. This can happen if gsutil is configured to save tracker files to an unwritable directory)
```

I am expecting this to copy entire set of files.

Please help me resolve this.